# float to string no scientific notation: SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have a problem with some wonky ID's that I can't quite figure out.

```
-------------------------------------------
|ID1                |    ID2              |
-------------------------------------------
|1.3787547414298E+18|  1378754741429799395|
-------------------------------------------
```

The above is a result of joining two tables, where `ID1 = ID2`.  `ID1` cannot be null, however `ID2` can be *null.*

What I'm attempting to arrive at is:

```
-------------------------------------------
|ID1                |    ID2              |
-------------------------------------------
|1378754741429799395|  1378754741429799395|
-------------------------------------------
```

So I can then drop the other column.  I've tried casting, str function, removing the period in the ingestion process, and I've been stuck for about 2 hours.

The data type for `ID1` is a `float`, whereas the data type for `ID2` is a `nvarchar`(which is what I want).

Comment: You are seeing that result in SSMS *results to grid*. What's the value when you change your output *results to text*. Also, can you confirm you are joining these tables on some other key?

Comment: I had actually thought of that and the results to text show the exact same values as results to grid.  The join is purely on ID1 to ID2.

Comment: Can you post some sample data (from both tables)?

Comment: You should  *never* use floating points for join keys, because what you see is not what you get.  The values are approximate.

Comment: Aside: Rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) govern how differing data types are converted by default, e.g. `NVarChar` to `Float`.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of... Data comes from a vendor and in this case botched up the ID column.  Was HOPING we could fix it, but I think this is a case where I need to request new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you join two tables on `ID1 = ID2` and the type of `ID1` is `float` and the type of `ID2` is `nvarchar`, the engine implicitly converts `nvarchar` into a `float`, not the other way around.

`float` type has max precision of [15 digits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), so your `nvarchar` value that has 19 digits is rounded with the loss of precision. After this, both original float value of `ID1` and converted float value of `ID2` are equal, so your join returns a row.

It is easy to check:

```
DECLARE @V1 float = 1.3787547414298E+18;
DECLARE @V2 nvarchar(30) = 1378754741429799395;

SELECT @V1, @V2, CAST(@V2 as float);
```

**Result**

```
1.3787547414298E+18    1378754741429799395    1.3787547414298E+18
```

---

It is impossible to convert `1.3787547414298E+18` into `1378754741429799395`, the `float` type simply doesn't have this data, the data has been lost.

You can try

```
SELECT CAST(@V1 as decimal(38))
```

and you'll get

```
1378754741429799936
```

If you use another method, you'll get different result. For example:

```
SELECT STR(@V1, 30, 0)
```

returns

```
1378754741429799900
```

---

Many different `nvarchar` values correspond to the same `float` value:

```
DECLARE @V2 nvarchar(30) = 1378754741429799395;
DECLARE @V3 nvarchar(30) = 1378754741429800000;
DECLARE @V4 nvarchar(30) = 1378754741429795000;
DECLARE @V5 nvarchar(30) = 1378754741429799400;
DECLARE @V6 nvarchar(30) = 1378754741429799999;

SELECT
     CAST(@V2 as float)
    ,CAST(@V3 as float)
    ,CAST(@V4 as float)
    ,CAST(@V5 as float)
    ,CAST(@V6 as float)
;
```

**Result**

```
1.3787547414298E+18 1.3787547414298E+18 1.3787547414298E+18 1.3787547414298E+18 1.3787547414298E+18
```

Comment: Awesome explanation as to the inner workings, greatly appreciated.